# Fitaly patent owner - ongoing development

Tags: us20030014239

How may one, such as I, contact the patent's owner?
Is the current patent owner developing the patent, or interested in the patent?

Answer (score 0):

The USPTO entry for the patent has a correspondence address listed for the IP law attorneys. You can contact them if you have questions about the owner's interest in pursuing the patent.

The link to the USPTO entry for this patent application is: http://appft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PG01&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/srchnum.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=20030014239.PGNR.